# webcam not enable in localhost server

Tags: jquery, html, webcam

I'm using this jQuery plugin: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

i put it webcam div in temp

```
   <div id="webcamTemp"  style="display:none" >
      <p id="status" />
     <div id="webcam">
            <object id="XwebcamXobjectX" width="320" height="240" data="/download   
            /jscam_canvas_only.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
          <param value="/download/jscam_canvas_only.swf" name="movie">
           <param value="mode=callback&quality=85" name="FlashVars">
            <param value="always" name="allowScriptAccess"></object> </div>
             <p style="width: 360px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">
          <a href="javascript:webcam.capture();changeFilter();void(0);">Take a picture 
                </a></p>
           <p> <canvas id="canvas" height="180" width="150"></canvas></p>
            <ul id="cams">
             </ul>
             </div>
```

This is my jquery code

```
         $('#webcamTemp').webcam({ 
         width: 320,
          height: 240,
          mode: "callback",
          swffile: "/download/jscam_canvas_only.swf",
              });
```

I am running this code on localhost.I am trying to get the webcam on the page to capture
 a photo but when i am trying to enable the camera ..it displays "error flash movie not
 yet registered!"

i don't know whats the problem.can any one help me.thank in advance.

Comment: already  i saw that link and tried those solutions ,but my webcam was not enable.

Comment: as the posting guidlines state, you should state what actions you have taken when posting a question. It would certainly have avoided 2 reports of a duplicate question. You would also avoid wasting the time of people that offer suggestions that you have already tried. I assume you intend to use 2 different folders to refer to `jscam_canvas_only.swf`? (you used both `download` and `Downloads`)

Comment: PLEASE - for the love of something special, update the question to reflect the change. Please remember that you're not paying for answers - it's your responsibility to make them as easy to answer as possible. Inconsistent/incorrect/missing information certainly doesn't help!